# Missing requirement package in OSGI Bundle

Tags: spring, maven, osgi, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to connect oracle database using org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate in OSGI bundle. When deploying bundle in servicemix , it shows error

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle My Second Service [376]: Unable to resolve 376.0: missing requirement [376.0] package; (package=org.springframework.jdbc.core)

And here is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.my.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../my-service/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>com.brodos.osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>my-second-service</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>My Second Service</name>
<url>http://example.net</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0-fuse-01-13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>My Second Service</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Description>My Second Service</Bundle-Description>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.apache.servicemix.camel.nmr,
                        org.apache.servicemix.nmr.api,
                        org.apache.servicemix.nmr.api.event,
                        org.apache.servicemix.nmr.api.internal,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Private-Package>com.test.osgi.*</Private-Package>
                    <Include-Resource>src/main/resources</Include-Resource>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the bundle that exports the `org.springframework.jdbc.core` package.

Answer (score 1):

Jignesh, this may be worth looking at:

Download this jar from [ebr.springsource.com](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.jdbc&version=2.5.6.A&searchType=bundlesByPackage&searchQuery=org.springframework.jdbc.core):

Since you are in an OSGi environment, you will also require other bundles like `org.springframework.osgi.core` `org.springframework.osgi.io` and `org.springframework.osgi.extender`. These will also require some additional bundles like `org.apache.commons`. You may have to fiddle a bit with MANIFEST.MF to match versions to make it run.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.jroller.com/dbrosius/entry/osgi_spring_dm_w_o) to get an idea: I was able to import and run this.

Note* As of now I am doing this integration manually...I hope to use maven as things get clear for me.